# Linker Problems: Target isn't x86

Tags: c++, linker, kdevelop

today i started coding c++ for windows, while always been Linux before. I use newest KDevelop with current windows build tools and newest CMake.
My problem is as follows: 
I have got a x64 .lib file of a hardware producer with a bunch of header and .dll files. First thing I learned is, that linking to the only given .lib most likely is enough to include the .dlls? (is this correct?) 
However as I try to build my project it says something like: "system is x64 while target machine is x86". I tried everything possible on the internet to change target to x64 like my system is. But I don't succeed. Is this a choice of compiler? And if yes, how do i change my compiler in kdevelop to x64? Why does he try to compile in x86 in the first place (everything i use is x64)?

Thanks for the hint and best regards,

Alex

Comment: to change compiler you need to edit your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I tried set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "path to /amd64/cl.exe"), but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution.
1) Delete build directory
2) Start CMake gui
3) Delete Cache if necessary
4) Hit generate and choose an installed, native VS amd64 compiler
5) Configure/Generate.

However I didn't find a solution to integrate that into Kdevelop environment, any suggestions?